# MS Access Error '2110' Can't move the focus to the control

Tags: ms-access

I'm a beginner using MS Access 2016.
I have a save button on a form that does some last minute input validation that is meant to be very direct and helpful to the end-user. I'm using a series of textboxes to step through the validation when they click the save button, this way they can complete then entire form and if there is an error it takes them directly to that field with the error.

My code appears to work, 
it detects an error, 
sets the focus to the text179, 
sees there is an error in the JobNo field, 
gives a message saying "Please enter a 5 digit job number"and 
sets the focus to JobNo. 
Then and only then, do I get a second prompt saying there is an error. 
But why is it saying it can't set the focus to text179 when it clearly already has done so and should no longer be trying at that point?

Here is my code:
`Private Sub SaveRecord_GotFocus()
    If Me.JobNo & "" Like "#####" And Me.ItemNo & "" <> "" Then
        Exit Sub
        Else
        Me.Text179.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub Text179_GotFocus()
    If Me.JobNo & "" Like "#####" Then
        Me.Text181.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
        Else
        MsgBox "Please enter a 5 digit Job Number", vbOKOnly
        Cancel = True
        Me.JobNo.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub`

Error:
Run-time error '2110':
Microsoft Access can't move the focus to the control Text179.

Let me know if any additional information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this with a much cleaner method, using just VB code without trying to use setfocus. It just took me a while to figure out how to nest my if statements correctly since I'm new with Access/VB. I'll post the code below.

`Private Sub SaveRecord_GotFocus()
    If Me.JobNo & "" Like "#####" Then
    GoTo Eval_ItemNo
        Else
    MsgBox "Please enter a 5 digit Job Number", vbOKOnly
    Me.JobNo.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
    End If
Eval_ItemNo:
    If Me.ItemNo & "" <> "" Then
    GoTo Eval_QtyFinished
    Else 
    MsgBox "Please enter an Item Number", vbOKOnly
        Me.ItemNo.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
    End If
Eval_QtyFinished:
    If Me.QtyFinished & "" <> "" Then
    GoTo Eval_WorkCenter
    Else
    MsgBox "Please enter a Qty Finished", vbOKOnly
        Me.QtyFinished.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
    End If
Eval_WorkCenter:
    If Me.WorkCenter & "" <> "" Then
    Exit Sub
    Else
    MsgBox "Please enter a WorkCenter", vbOKOnly
        Me.WorkCenter.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub`